# Parametrized Spock test using @WithMockUser

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, annotations, spock

I'd like to run a parametrized test in Spock using the @WithMockUser with a different role per each iteration.

As an example, the following test code shows no compilation error and is run twice.
But the result fails, since the #role is resolved only in the @Unroll, but not in the @WithMockUser annotation.

```
    @Unroll("#role is authorized to get admin")
    @WithMockUser(username = "user", roles = ["#role"])
    def "User is authorized to get admin"() {
        when:
        def adminDto = adminController.getAdmin()

        then:
        adminDto.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK

        where:
        role << ["USER", "ADMIN"]
    }
```

So my question is: **Is it possible to run such a test as a parametrized one?**

Thank you in advance!

*Note: I'm aware the annotation could look like:*

```
@WithMockUser(username = "user", roles = ["USER", "ADMIN"])
```

but this would be a different behavior - one call with both roles.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer no.

The annotations are statically compiled at compile time and cannot be modified by Spock, the iterations are generated/evaluated dynamically at runtime.
The `@Unroll` annotation has some special support for data variables to make it work, while the Spring annotation doesn't know anything about Spock.

You could look at [WithMockUserSecurityContextFactory](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/d5c953b10603202d44c4c9c03a544c14a630213d/test/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/test/context/support/WithMockUserSecurityContextFactory.java) and use that to manually set the the `SecurityContext` in the `given` block.